# Problem using PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pythonpath

I'm trying to use `PYTHONPATH` to let Python know where my library is located, but it seems to ignore it:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/osqa/EC2/backup/src/boto/
$ ls /home/osqa/EC2/backup/src/boto/boto/ec2/connection.py
/home/osqa/EC2/backup/src/boto/boto/ec2/connection.py

$ python backup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
ImportError: No module named boto.ec2.connection
```

Comment: @Kalus - that should be an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/osqa/EC2/backup/src/
```

instead, i.e. use `export` and remove the last path component.

Comment: without the last path component, the import will be "from boto.boto.ec2.connection", and will probably fail horribly due to a missing `__init__.py` given the likely directory structure.

Comment: Actually, I don't need to remove the last path component, since I have a boto folder inside the boto folder. But export did the trick!

Comment: @ripper234: Missed the `/boto/boto` part, but the problem seems to be solved anayway :)

Comment: I would have accepted your answer sooner if SO had allowed me to :)